# Validation on dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm cloning a row and I want to check in the database if the code exists.  This all works fine on the first row but not on the cloned rows.  I have an idea that I have to make the id of the field unique, I have tried to add the the code that checks if the code exist to the add button event but it doesn't work.  Can someone please tell me how to merge the two script so it works on the cloned rows.

Code:

HTML

```
<table>
<tr id="show_codes">
    <td colspan="2" class="text-fields" align="center" valign="middle">
        <div class="codeForm">
            <table class="codeForm" align="left" width="500px" cellpadding="0" style="padding-left: 20px;" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td height="15px">Codes that exist is 0011, 1234</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="code_row">
                    <td class="details-border1" height="40px" valign="middle" bgcolor="#f3f3f3" align="center">
                        <input id="code" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" type="text" name="code[]" />
                        <div id="status"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="details-border2" bgcolor="#f3f3f3" align="center">
                        <input value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" type="text" name="value[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="borders-right-bottom" bgcolor="#f3f3f3" align="center">
                        <input type="button" class="btnDeleteCode" value="Delete" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table width="500px" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><span style="cursor: pointer; color: #007FC6; font-weight: bold;" id="btnAddCode" value="add more">Add another code</span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JQUERY

```
var dom = {};
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);

dom.query(document).ready(function () {

    var clonedRow = dom.query('.code_row').clone().html();
    var appendRow = '<tr class = "code_row">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';
    var counter = 0;
    dom.query('#btnAddCode').click(function () {

        dom.query('.codeForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
        counter++;
        $('.codeForm tr:last input[type="text"]').attr('id', 'code[' + counter + ']');
        $('.codeForm tr:last').find('input').val('');
    });

    dom.query('.btnDeleteCode').live('click', function () {
        var rowLength = dom.query('.code_row').length;
        if (rowLength > 1) {
            deleteRow(this);
        } else {
            dom.query('.codeForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
            deleteRow(this);
        }
    });

    function deleteRow(currentNode) {
        dom.query(currentNode).parent().parent().remove();
    }
});

pic1 = new Image(16, 16);
pic1.src = "loader.gif";

pic2 = new Image(16, 16);
pic2.src = "tick.gif";

dom.query(document).ready(function () {

    dom.query("#code").change(function () {

        var usr = dom.query("#code").val();

        if (usr.length >= 4) {
            dom.query("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
            alert(usr);
            dom.query.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "setup_practice_preference_check_code.php",
                data: "username=" + usr,
                success: function (msg) {

                    dom.query("#status").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {

                        if (msg == 'OK') {
                            dom.query("#code").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                            dom.query("#code").addClass("object_ok");
                            dom.query(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
                        } else {
                            alert('msg');
                            dom.query("#code").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                            dom.query("#code").addClass("object_error");
                            dom.query(this).html(msg);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        } else {
            dom.query("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
            dom.query("#code").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
            dom.query("#code").addClass("object_error");
        }
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zSJa/)

Thanks

Comment: are you having problem in delete ?

Comment: No the cloning works fine. I need to check if a code exits, this also works fine but only on the first row and not the cloned rows.

Comment: what do u mean by 'code exits'?

Comment: I'm validating the code in the database to see if it exists,  As you type it checks the database.